# Tags should be plurals (with a few caveats)

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

Hey travellers I'd just like to revisit an old issue: [Plural tags should be the lead tag](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/plurals-and-tags) in a set of tag synonyms.

At least that's what we seemed to decide from the clickvoting back then.

Somehow at least a couple of reversals have slipped through the cracks:

- <s>[airports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airports) redirects to [airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airport). Can a friendly diamond please swap this around?</s>
- [ferries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ferries) redirects to [ferry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ferry). Can a friendly diamond please swap this around?

**Caveats**

Rather than be taken too literally and have a few semiautomatic pluralitybots misquoting me let me qualify that English is quirky and sometimes the singular is better.

Some nouns refer to "things" and some refer to "stuff" and some work for both.

If something is "stuff" then the singular tag is probably better even if the word can be plural too. For instance "food" is a better tag than "foods".

If something is an abstract concept then the singular tag is better. For instance "travel" is better than "travels".

If the plural only occurs in Euroenglish the singular tag is better. For instance "advice" is better than "advices".

If in doubt try using the tag you are thinking of in an English sentence of the form "I like ABC". For instance "I like backpacks" is better than "I like backpack" but "I like beer" is better than "I like beers".

Another test is to imagine you're writing an article or paper on the topic. For instance "Ferries" is better than "Ferry" and "Camping" is better than "Campings".

---

<sup>OK it seems like a bit of a rant for only one wrong tag that I spotted but I think some guidelines that will survive to be pointed at and enhanced long into the future when we might have lots of noobs is a good thing to have.</sup>

Comment: Swap done for `airports`.

Comment: Thank you Mr Diamond (-:

Comment: Done for the ferries, but still some troubles with synonims. Try to solve this later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We generally agree that network wide, the preferred tag is always the plural form unless there is some clear and compelling reason to use the singular version.