# Revenge of the singular tags: Change "backpack" to "backpacks"

Tags: support, tagging

Personally I'm not convinced we need a "backpacks" tag since we already have [luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luggage), [gear](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gear), and [backpacking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backpacking).

But either way, we long ago decided that plural tags are [(usually)](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/tags-should-be-plurals-with-a-few-caveats) the way to go so can a moderator please rename the [backpack](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backpack) tag to [backpacks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backpacks)?

Comment: Er, I think you meant plural tags are the way to go, no?

Comment: Excuse me while I unknot my tongue. And detangle my brain. (-:

Comment: I see this has been done. Why not answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the tag [backpack](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backpack) was renamed [backpacks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backpacks) sometime in 2013. (The latter version presently in use for 12 Open questions).

Seems [status-completed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) may be appropriate here.