# New singular tags, mid 2014

Tags: support, tagging

I've spotted one that needs to be changed. Please alert us to any others:

(Don't forget that singular is *not always* bad, and plural is *not always* the best way to improve it even if it is bad. [Read more about that.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/tags-should-be-plurals-with-a-few-caveats?rq=1))

- [upgrade](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade) -> [upgrades](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrades) *or* [upgrading](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[upgrade](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade) has been synonymised to [upgrades](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrades). May be time to mark OP as [status-completed].