# Tags should be plurals. "castle" should be "castles", etc

Tags: support, tagging

We've already discussed that [tags should be plurals](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/plurals-and-tags) and [it's come up since](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/tags-should-be-plurals-with-a-few-caveats). I'm still finding a few singular tags.

I could re-tag the question but for some of these tags a tag wiki and/or excerpt has already been written and it might be a bit rude to accidentally dump it by leaving the tag as an orphan and adding a new blank tag in its place.

If a diamond could either rename the singular to the plural or leave the singular as a synonym, whichever they think is the best solution:

- <s>[castle](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castle) -> [castles](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castles)</s>
- <s>[camper](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camper) -> [campers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/campers)</s>
- <s>[mountain](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountain) -> [mountains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountains)</s>
- [border](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/border) -> [borders](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borders)
- [passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passport) -> [passports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passports)
- [exchange-rate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange-rate) -> [exchange-rates](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange-rates)
- [road-trip](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/road-trip) -> [road-trips](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/road-trips)
- [bus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bus) -> [buses](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buses)
- [travel-mate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-mate) -> [travel-mates](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-mates)
- [visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa) -> [visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visas)
- [simcard](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcard) -> [simcards](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcards)
- [train](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/train) -> [trains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trains)
- [eclipse](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) -> [eclipses](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipses)

Wow we really have heaps of these left. I'm surprised we didn't notice.

Makes me wonder if it really is worth it. It does seem to come up sooner or later on most SE sites though that it's the more professional way to do it. Anyway here's a bunch more for the list...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done, with new update for [mountains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountains)

Comment: I must be going blind, but I can't find how to edit a tag anywhere.  Can change the tag wiki, but aside from retagging or synonymising, I'm not seeing a place to edit a specific tag?

Comment: You can't edit tags. I use merge tags in instead.

Answer (score 1):

(I assume 'someone else' is Ankur)

Updated list:

- <s>[castle](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castle) -> [castles](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castles)</s> - someone else has done
- <s>[camper](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camper) -> [campers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/campers)</s> - someone else has done
- <s>[mountain](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountain) -> [mountains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountains)</s> - someone else has done
- <s>[border](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/border) -> [borders](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borders)</s> - someone else has done
- <s>[passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passport) -> [passports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passports)</s> - someone else has done
- <s>[exchange-rate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange-rate) -> [exchange-rates](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange-rates)</s> (fixed some spelling in the description too)
- <s>[road-trip](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/road-trip) -> [road-trips](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/road-trips)</s> - someone else has done
- <s>[bus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bus) -> [buses](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buses)</s> - someone else has done
- <s>[travel-mate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-mate) -> [travel-mates](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-mates)</s> - someone else has done
- <s>[visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa) -> [visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visas)</s> - someone else has done
- <s>[simcard](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcard) -> [simcards](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcards)</s> - done
- <s>[train](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/train) -> [trains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trains)</s> - someone else has done
- <s>[eclipse](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) -> [eclipses](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipses)</s> - someone else has done

Other ones I've spotted that I've also done:

- <s>[travel-agent](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-agent) -> [travel-agents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-agents)</s>

Questionable ones:

- [budget](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budget) - do we really want plural here?
- [adventure](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure) - do we really want plural here?
- [language-barrier](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-barrier) - do we really want plural here?

Comment: As per **[my rant "plurals with caveats"](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/336/tags-should-be-plurals-with-a-few-caveats)** these all work better in the singular. "Budget" and "adventure" we use more as adjectives "budget trip", "adventure travel". "Adventure" also works as an abstract noun or mass noun, "a bit of adventure", and "language barrier" is definite - it's "the language barrier". They would all sound a bit different and wrong in our context. **So yeah these ones should be left singular.**