# What price to pay for tag consistency?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Citizenship and residence tags at present use the adjectival form. For example [italian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italian-citizens) and [italian-residents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italian-residents) rather than [italy-citizens] and [italy-residents]. There are lots of citizenship tags:

[afghan-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afghan-citizens)
[albanian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/albanian-citizens)
[algerian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algerian-citizens)
[armenian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/armenian-citizens)
[australian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian-citizens)
[austrian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/austrian-citizens)
[azerbaijani-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azerbaijani-citizens)
[bahamian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bahamian-citizens)
[bangladeshi-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bangladeshi-citizens)
[belarusian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belarusian-citizens)
[belgian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belgian-citizens)
[bosnian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bosnian-citizens)
[brazilian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brazilian-citizens)
[british-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/british-citizens)
[bulgarian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulgarian-citizens)
[cameroonian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cameroonian-citizens)
[canadian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canadian-citizens)
[chilean-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chilean-citizens)
[chinese-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese-citizens)
[colombian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colombian-citizens)
[costa-rican-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/costa-rican-citizens)
[croatian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/croatian-citizens)
[cuban-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cuban-citizens)
[danish-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danish-citizens)
[dominican-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dominican-citizens)
[dutch-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dutch-citizens)
[ecuadorian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecuadorian-citizens)
[egyptian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/egyptian-citizens)
[eritrean-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eritrean-citizens)
[ethiopian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethiopian-citizens)
[eu-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu-citizens)
[fijian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fijian-citizens)
[filipino-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filipino-citizens)
[finnish-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finnish-citizens)
[french-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french-citizens)
[german-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-citizens)
[ghanaian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghanaian-citizens)
[greek-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek-citizens)
[guatemalan-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guatemalan-citizens)
[guyanese-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guyanese-citizens)
[haitian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haitian-citizens)
[honduran-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/honduran-citizens)
[hong-kong-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hong-kong-citizens)
[hungarian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hungarian-citizens)
[indian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-citizens)
[indonesian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indonesian-citizens)
[iranian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iranian-citizens)
[iraqi-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iraqi-citizens)
[iraqi-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iraqi-citizens)
[irish-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irish-citizens)
[israeli-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israeli-citizens)
[italian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italian-citizens)
[jamaican-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jamaican-citizens)
[japanese-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese-citizens)
[jordanian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jordanian-citizens)
[kenyan-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kenyan-citizens)
[kuwaiti-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kuwaiti-citizens)
[kyrgyz-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kyrgyz-citizens)
[lebanese-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lebanese-citizens)
[libyan-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libyan-citizens)
[liechtenstein-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liechtenstein-citizens)
[lithuanian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithuanian-citizens)
[macedonian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macedonian-citizens)
[malagasy-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malagasy-citizens)
[malaysian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malaysian-citizens)
[maltese-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maltese-citizens)
[mauritian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mauritian-citizens)
[mexican-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mexican-citizens)
[moldovan-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moldovan-citizens)
[mongolian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mongolian-citizens)
[moroccan-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moroccan-citizens)
[mozambican-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mozambican-citizens)
[myanmar-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myanmar-citizens)
[nepali-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nepali-citizens)
[new-zealand-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-zealand-citizens)
[nicaraguan-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nicaraguan-citizens)
[nigerian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nigerian-citizens)
[norwegian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norwegian-citizens)
[pakistani-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pakistani-citizens)
[peruvian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peruvian-citizens)
[polish-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polish-citizens)
[portuguese-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portuguese-citizens)
[romanian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romanian-citizens)
[russian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-citizens)
[salvadoran-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salvadoran-citizens)
[saudi-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saudi-citizens)
[singaporean-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singaporean-citizens)
[south-african-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-african-citizens)
[spanish-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish-citizens)
[sri-lankan-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sri-lankan-citizens)
[sudanese-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudanese-citizens)
[swazi-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swazi-citizens)
[swedish-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swedish-citizens)
[swiss-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swiss-citizens)
[syrian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syrian-citizens)
[taiwanese-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taiwanese-citizens)
[tajikistani-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tajikistani-citizens)
[t-and-t-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t-and-t-citizens)
[thai-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thai-citizens)
[tunisian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tunisian-citizens)
[turkish-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turkish-citizens)
[emiri-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emiri-citizens)
[ugandan-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ugandan-citizens)
[uk-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-citizens)
[ukrainian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ukrainian-citizens)
[us-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizens)
[uzbek-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uzbek-citizens)
[venezuelan-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/venezuelan-citizens)
[vietnamese-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vietnamese-citizens)
[yemeni-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yemeni-citizens)
[zambian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zambian-citizens)
[zimbabwean-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zimbabwean-citizens)

and some residency tags:

[australian-residents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian-residents)
[dutch-residents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dutch-residents)
[german-residents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-residents)
[italian-residents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italian-residents)
[uk-residents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-residents)
[us-residents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-residents)

The above may not be fully comprehensive but does indicate extensive use of the adjectival form. A very small number of the above are broken at present but have already been sent to the shop for repair (our master mechanic RoflcopterException is working on them).

For the country-specific Schengen visa tags however we have the [locality](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/country-citizen-tags-convention-needed) form:

[france-schengen-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/france-schengen-visas)
[germany-schengen-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany-schengen-visas)
[greece-schengen-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greece-schengen-visas)
[italy-schengen-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italy-schengen-visas)
[netherlands-schengen-visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands-schengen-visa)

The last being singular, despite [Jeff's advice](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/600/4995) because it has hit the 25 character limit for a tag. (Mind you Dori, I think a CM at the time, was of a [slightly different opinion](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/58/4995).)

Change the country-specific Schengen visa tags to adjectival form and we could be consistent for both form and plurals (by choosing [dutch-schengen-visas]).

Is it worth it?

Comment: Vote below please. My own vote is for consistency.

Comment: The 5 tags specified by @pnuts have been renamed. There hasn't been strong consensus on how to proceed, so I chose the most logical option - to go for consistency. The tags have also been synonymized, so they're available for users to look-up.

Answer (score 2):

Disagreed. Leave as is. The tags are better that way.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed. All geographical tags should be in the plural form.